# Unable to connect windows 7 to a network.

Tags: networking

No matter what I do I am unable to get a windows 7 computer to connect to any networks. Wired or wireless, I always get a "limited access" error. I have searched google for possible solutions and have been u able to find any

Comment: Gonna need more info.  Is this DHCP? Static?

Comment: What does ipconfig in your command prompt yield?

Comment: While connected to a network that should give you access: Go to Control Panel>Network and Sharing Center>Wireless Network Connection (or however you are connected)>Properties>Click on Internet Protocol Version 4 so it is highlighted>click properties. Is 'Obtain an IP address automatically' selected along with 'Obtain DNS server address automatically'?

Comment: I have checked all the settings for ipv4. It is auto dhcp and ipconfig looks normal minus an invalid ip address.

Comment: @TheX could you update your question with the output of `ipconfig /all`?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for the longest time when troubleshooting my neighbors computer. After about a four hour headache I ran System File Checker. This fixed it instantly.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Comment: Yeah yes I remember having to do this before. Thanks for reminding me. I will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling the driver and reinstalling the driver and reboot your computer 
I encountered a problem similar to yours at a pharmacy that needed technical support.

Also try to reset the router and then see what happens.

Comment: Whoops wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its most likely a driver error. Check your device manager and make sure that you have a network adapter driver, and that its up to date, (IE there isn't a little exclamation mark next to it.) If you recently installed windows, its possible that you either didn't install the network card/driver, or that its not properly configured. What kind of laptop do you have? I would recommend going to the manufacturer site and manually updating your drivers.

Comment: I have tried 3 different network adapters 2 of them I know work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't fill "Default gateway" for TCP/IP v4?

Comment: Default gateway is not required for IPv4 but it is sensible to use it. For DHCP, it should be set for you though not all routers provide it.

Comment: AFAIK, gateway is "required" for Windows 7, otherwise network will be "Unidentified".

Comment: You might be right about W7, I can't confirm because all of my networks have it set correctly - I am "old school" after all ;)